# Reading file line by line and print

Tags: java, file, lines, skip

I'm trying to write a program that takes the file name from the user (for example: English), then opens this file and prints (9 questions) divided on (3 levels, each level has 3 questions), then opens another file (`EnglishC`) that contains the answers and then compares it with the correct answer.  if correct `grade++`.

**Output:**

```
enter your choice:
1.English
2.Math
3.Science

java.io.FileNotFoundException: English.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:636)
at Generater.createQuestions(Generater.java:50)
at Generater.choose_subject_And_Level(Generater.java:41)
at Generater.main(Generater.java:139)
```

**Source:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Generater {
static int levelNo = 1;
static int subjectName;
static int grade;
static String fileName;
static String fileNameCorrect;
static String ans;
static String correctAns;

public static void choose_subject_And_Level() {
    // here the main will call this method to ask the user what subject to be tested in?
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("enter your choice:\n 1.English\n2.Math\n3.Science ");
    subjectName = input.nextInt();

    switch (subjectName) {
    case 1:
        fileName = "English.txt";
        fileNameCorrect = "EnglishC.txt";
        break;
    case 2:
        fileName = "Math.txt";
        fileNameCorrect = "MathC.txt";
        break;
    case 3:
        fileName = "Science.txt";
        fileNameCorrect = "SienceC.txt";
        break;
    }

    createQuestions(fileName, fileNameCorrect, levelNo);

}

public static void createQuestions(String fileName, String fileNameCorrect,
        int levelNo) {

    Scanner input, input2;
    try {
        input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        input2 = new Scanner(new File(fileNameCorrect));
        input.useDelimiter("*");

        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        FileInputStream fs2 = new FileInputStream(fileNameCorrect);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs2));!

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            switch (levelNo) {
            case 1:
                for (int i = 1,k=1; i <= 3 ; i++,k++) {
                    System.out.printf("\nQ#\f: " + input.next() + "\n" , k);

                    ans = input.next();

                    correctAns = input2.next();

                    if (ans == correctAns) {
                        grade++;
                    }
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                for (int i = 4, k = 1; i <= 6; i++, k++) {

                    try {
                        for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
                            br.readLine();
                            correctAns = br2.readLine();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.printf("\nQ#\f: " + input.next() + "\n" , k);

                    ans = input.next();                 

                    if (ans == correctAns) {
                        grade++;
                    }
                }
                break;

            case 3:
                for (int i = 7, k = 1; i <= 9; i++, k++) {

                    try {
                        for (int j = 1; j <= 6 ; j++){
                            br.readLine();
                            correctAns = br2.readLine();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    System.out.printf("\nQ#\f: " + input.next() + "\n" , k);

                    ans = input.next();

                    correctAns = input2.next();

                    if (ans == correctAns) {
                        grade++;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

// the main
public static void main(String[] args) {

    choose_subject_And_Level();

}
}
```

Comment: Please remove the link to a picture of your error and paste the actual error text in your question.  Most people don't want to follow links to see your error

Answer (score 1):

When java.io.FileNotFoundException is thrown it means the file that is supposed to be read/written is not present at the location specified. Look where you have the file on the filesystem and confirm that the file in question (English.txt) is present.

More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html

Comment: This is a comment and no answer.

Comment: Ok , I've missed that. Edited my answer :)

Comment: the file is already in the same folder of the project, is there any thing wrong in my code?